# subprocess.check_output() for python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I have a function written in python 3.7 which uses subprocess.check_output() function to run commands. I need to convert the function to python 2.7 compatible, keeping the functionality of the function same. I am not sure what will be the new parameters for the arguments in python 2.7 in check_output() function based on the parameters used in python 3.6.
I am specifically not aware of the equivalent of sp.DEVNULL in python 2.7. I couldn't get much from the python standard document (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL). I feel this argument might be important considering the comment above the check_output() function mentions why it is being used.

```
def _run_command(command):
    try:
        # The stdin=sp.DEVNULL below is needed so that ffmpeg does not mess up
        # the terminal.
        sp.check_output(command, stdin=sp.DEVNULL, stderr=sp.PIPE)
    except sp.CalledProcessError as exc:
        msg = ("operations._run_command failed.\n"
               "Command was: {}.\n"
               "Standard error was: {}.\n"
               "Exit code was: {}").format(exc.cmd, exc.stderr.decode(),
                                           exc.returncode)
        logger.error(msg, extra=JOB_RUNNING)
        raise exc
```

If someone can explain what do the arguments and their parameters mean in the sp.check_output() function and what would be their suitable replacement in python 2.7.

Comment: Check this out: https://pypi.org/project/subprocess32/

Comment: @Selcuk using subprocess32, solved my problem. Thanks